# glMapBuffer causes glDrawElementsInstanced to fail with GL_INVALID_OPERATION error

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an issue with glMapBuffer on windows

The following code works fine, and the scene renders

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, from, to, bufferData)
```

But if I try to map the buffer and change glBufferSubData with memcpy like this

```
mappedBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
memcpy(mappedBuffer, (char *)bufferData + from, to);
```

Then I get this error

```
OpenGL error
Debug message (1000): glDrawElementsInstanced has generated an error (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
Source: API
Type: Error
Severity: high
```

In macos this works just fine so I wonder if I'm really doing a mistake.

Also I find quite strange that the error happens when glDrawElementsInstanced gets called instead of failing on the glMapBuffer call.

Comment: Did you `glUnmapBuffer()` after the `memcpy()`? From [glUnmapBuffer()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUnmapBuffer.xhtml): _If a mapping is not unmapped before the corresponding buffer object's data store is used by the GL, an error will be generated by any GL command that attempts to dereference the buffer object's data store, unless the buffer was successfully mapped with GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT (see glMapBufferRange)._

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to use glUnmapBuffer after memcpy, for some reason on macos is not needed